# react native flex - button doesn't respect "alignSelf"

Tags: react-native

"[alignSelf](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#alignself) controls how a child aligns in the cross direction, overriding the alignItems of the parent. It works like align-self in CSS (default: auto)."

The default "alignItems" is "stretch", therefore by default elements within the view should attempt to stretch to the full width. setting "alignSelf" to "flex-start" should in theory cause the item to not stretch, and appear in the far left.

This works as expected for `<Text>` elements, why doesn't it work for `<Button>`?

Starting with an example of the basic premise:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}>Hello</Text>
</View>
```

^ the blue text element is the full width of the screen

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    <Button style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>Hello</Text>
</View>
```

^ The blue text element is in the far left and only the width of its text

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    <Button style={{ }} title="here" />
</View>
```

^ the button element is the full width of the screen

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
    <Button style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }} title="here" />
</View>
```

**^ the button element is STILL the full width of the screen**

I need to override the View's alignItems of stretch (default) because I have many elements also in the view that I would like to stretch. Therefore it will be much more convenient to have the default behaviour "stretch".

This demo shows how Button has Zero respect for "alignSelf":

```
        <View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "stretch", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start", backgroundColor: "green" }}>don''t stretch me</Text>
                <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>stretch me</Text>
                <Button style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }} title="don't stretch me" />
                <Button style={{}} title="stretch me" />
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-start", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>don''t stretch me</Text>
                <Text style={{ alignSelf: "stretch", backgroundColor: "green" }}>stretch me</Text>
                <Button style={{}} title="don't stretch me" />
                <Button style={{ alignSelf: "stretch" }} title="stretch me" />
            </View>
        </View>
```

renders:

```
| don't stretch me |
| stretch me                                   |
[                 DON'T STRETCH ME             ]
[                     STRETCH ME               ]
| don't stretch me |
| stretch me                                   |
[ DON'T STRETCH ME ]
[ STRETCH ME ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I wrap a Button inside a View. It will work perfectly

```
<View style = {styles.container}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "stretch", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <Text style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start", backgroundColor: "green" }}>don''t stretch me</Text>
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>stretch me</Text>
        <View style = {{alignSelf:'flex-start'}}>
        <Button style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }} title="don't stretch me" />
        </View>
        <Button style={{}} title="stretch me" />
    </View>

    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "flex-start", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>don''t stretch me</Text>
        <Text style={{ alignSelf: "stretch", backgroundColor: "green" }}>stretch me</Text>
        <View style = {{alignSelf:'flex-start'}}>
        <Button style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }} title="don't stretch me" />
        </View>
        <View style = {{alignSelf:'stretch'}}>
        <Button  title="stretch me" />
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: yeah, in reality I have many other elements in the view, all of which need to stretch. which is why I want the Button to override the default. I'll update the question.

Comment: `flexDirection:"column"` is the problem. If I change `flexDirection:"row"` it works fine

Comment: again, the examples were over-simplified. i in fact have many items in this view which are supposed to render in "column" mode

Comment: Check above my code. It will work perfectly what you are except.

Comment: Mainly Button component doesn't accept any style property.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what styles you put in 'Button'
It just doesn't support the 'style' prop.

you will have to use a container ('View') styling to make changes of the positions.

Comment: do you mean wrap it in it's own view?

Comment: Yap correct.
according to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html , it only supports 'color' prop.